# sum of time giving one hour extra in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I am trying to calculate sum of time. Everything is working fine but sum of time displaying one hour extra. For example if sum of time need to be 20:23, its displaying 21:23.  I dont knew why its given one hour extra in sum. (i came to knew via google, it can be solved by DateTimeImmutable but i dont knew how to use, as i never  did it before) here is my code :

```
 $sql = "SELECT *, TIME_TO_SEC(wrktime) as bbb1 FROM tmmach ORDER BY ddd DESC LIMIT 30";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Emp-Id</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Company</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>worktime</th>";
     echo "<th>worktime</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        $totalWorkTime = 0; // Initialize the variable for sum

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['empid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['empname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['company1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date1'])) . "</td>";
 
            echo "<td>" . $row['wrktime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['bbb1'] . "</td>";

            // Update the sum variable
            $totalWorkTime += $row['bbb1'];
            $hhh = date('H:i',$totalWorkTime);   
  
  
            


            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody>";

        // Display the sum row
        echo "<tfoot>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='4'><strong>Total Work Time:</strong></td>";
      echo "<td><strong>" . $hhh . "</strong></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tfoot>";

        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><em>No records were found.</em></div>';
    }


                    }
```

Comment: show what you tried?  what is "rollover"? not clear if you want a grant total time or per employee, not clear what type the wrktime column is

Comment: please provide any needed information in the text of your question, not images

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: @ADyson sir i tried to convert seconds into time format, but getting one extra hour. for example total sum need to be 20:55 but its displaying 21:55. here is my code                $totalWorkTime += $row['bbb1'];
            $hhh = date('H:i',$totalWorkTime);

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have new code or information to share. This isn't like a forum. See also [ask]. Also we can't check that code because we dont know what data is in `$row['bbb1']; ` - you need to provide sample data to make it clearer for everyone.

Comment: @ADyson sir i edited my question, please check and guide

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the sum of the "worktime" column, you can initialize a variable before the loop to accumulate the values and update it within the loop. Here's a modified version of your code to include the sum calculation:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM timetablw ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Emp-Id</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Company</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>worktime</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        $totalWorkTime = 0; // Initialize the variable for sum

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['empid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['empname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['company1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date1'])) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['wrktime'] . "</td>";

            // Update the sum variable
            $totalWorkTime += $row['wrktime'];

            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody>";

        // Display the sum row
        echo "<tfoot>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='4'><strong>Total Work Time:</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . $totalWorkTime . "</strong></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tfoot>";

        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><em>No records were found.</em></div>';
    }
}
```

This modification includes a variable `$totalWorkTime` that is initialized before the loop and updated within the loop to accumulate the values. The total sum is then displayed in a new row in the table footer. Adjust the formatting as needed.

Comment: Thanks alot sir! but this code only sum hours and ignoring minutes. I edited your code and later make it to work for minute as well. but the issue is that its now displaying one hour extra

Answer (score 0):

You may obtain needed total sum in the query:

```
SELECT empid, 
       IF(GROUPING(empid, empname, company), 'TOTAL', empname) empname, 
       company, 
       SUM(wrktime) wrktime
FROM timetablw
GROUP BY empid, empname, company WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(empid, empname, company) IN (0, 7)
ORDER BY GROUPING(empid, empname, company), empid, empname, company
```

Adjust `SUM(wrktime)` with according expression (depends on `wrktime` datatype and format).